# SSRS: Action - Making the entire textbox a link, not just the text

Tags: reporting-services, ssrs-2008-r2

I am using SSRS 2008-R2

I have a textbox in a tablix/matrix, for usage as a menu bar, which links correctly to given reports (four to be exact).

The textbox is using a background image, to represent a button.

However, only the text inside the textbox is a link to the report, i want to be able to use the entire box, which is formed by the background image.

Is there a way to alter the 'action' so the entire box is clickable?

Alternatives, like using an image, is also very welcome!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can't make the whole text box a link but you can put your Action on the Image instead.

In the Image properties, there is an Action tab that works the same as the Action tab on the text box which should work when the user clicks on it.

[image]